# Prisma cannot authenticate database server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prisma

I'm using docker to initiate a postgres db:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: db_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: db_password
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
volumes:
    postgres:
```

and in my `/.env` file I have:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db_user:db_password@localhost:5432/college_db?schema=public"
```

I start docker:

```
PS C:\Users\alucardu\Documents\projects\**-react> docker-compose up -d
Starting **-react_postgres_1 ... done
```

Check if the server is running:

```
PS C:\Users\alucardu\Documents\projects\**-react> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE         COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
e0f9233ce34b   postgres:13   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago   Up 33 seconds   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   **-react_postgres_1
```

But when I run a Prisma migrate I get an authentication error:

```
PS C:\Users\alucardu\Documents\projects\movieseat-react> npx prisma migrate dev --name "init"
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "college_db", schema "public" at "localhost:5432"

Error: P1000: Authentication failed against database server at `localhost`, the provided database credentials for `db_user` are not valid.

Please make sure to provide valid database credentials for the database server at `localhost`.
```

Why is Prisma not matching the set `db_user` and `db_password` to the environment variables created in the docker yml?

//edit.

I've added a `college_db` database and a superuser called `db_user` and made it owner of the `college_db`:

[image]

But I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Issue is probably because of host resolving. Have you tried `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost ?

Comment: `P1000: Authentication failed against database server at `127.0.0.1`, the provided database credentials for `db_user` are not valid.`, too bad no effect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What-a-mistaka-to-make. I had postgres installed locally on my Windows machine. So it was using that instance of postgres instead of the one on my docker environment. I removed the windows postgres installation and everything is working as expected. https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/8927

Comment: Had the same issue and was pulling my hair cus I could connect fine from my WSL xD thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is a database name mismatch.

Try adding `POSTGRES_DB: college_db` environment variable to your postgres container.

By default the init container uses POSTGRES_USER value for the database name.

Comment: Makes sense, but it's not the issue. I've added the `POSTGRES_DB` to the variables, but still the same error.

Comment: Have you deleted also the volume when you tried?

Comment: Yes, I've removed everything that was currently running in docker and rerun docker compose.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having this problem, check if you have postgres installed on the machine without docker and check if postgres is started on Windows and stop this process and try again

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPzYF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and doing a cleanup on my docker solve the problem for me (Be carreful, this is the hard way and it will erase all docker containers / images / volumes):

```
docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
docker builder prune
```

You can also target the containers / volumes to erase instead of removing all of it:

```
docker stop <container-id>
docker rm <container-id>
docker volume rm <volume-id>
docker builder prune
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the quote from the port and edit to match below

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: db_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: db_password
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
volumes:
    postgres:
```

OR

```yaml
ersion: '3.8'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: db_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: db_password
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
      - 5432
    ports:
      - 5432
volumes:
    postgres:
```